# Feature request: Chat stars by me ordered by most recent

Tags: feature-request, chat, sorting, chat-stars

If I visit http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/the-tavern-general/?tab=stars&mine=true I get a lovely little list of starred comments, but I can't find the ones that I starred most recently (not necessarily when I starred them, but the most recent comments first).

How can I do so? Do we need to add the ability to sort "newest | stars" as so many other pages on the site do?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208837/order-starred-chat-posts-by-stars