# Order starred chat posts by stars

Tags: feature-request, chat, sorting, chat-stars

When I look at the starred posts in a chatroom, they're [not ordered by stars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67672/), even though [the list of posts starred by me is *only* ordered by stars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81080/). I would like the ability to sort all starred posts (or just the most-starred ones) by stars so I can see what got starred the most.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81080/feature-request-chat-stars-by-me-ordered-by-most-recent